# Constrainted optimization: merge two constraints into one

Tags: optimization

Consider the following problem
\begin{align}
&\max_u F(x,u)\\
\text{s.t. }& u \in [0,\bar u].
\end{align}

Any idea how to merge the two constraints $u \geq 0$ and $\bar u - u \geq 0$ into one constraint $f(u,\bar u) \geq 0$?

Comment: Sure. Define the function $f$ so that $f(u,\bar{u}) = -1$ if $u < 0$ or $\bar{u} - u < 0$, and otherwise let $f(u,\bar{u}) = 0$. This is a well defined function. Perhaps you would like to include that $f$ is differentiable or some similar condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0\leq u \leq \bar u  \implies -\frac {\bar u}{2} \leq u - \frac {\bar u}{2} \leq \frac {\bar u}{2}$$

$$\implies \left | u - \frac {\bar u}{2}\right| \leq \frac {\bar u}{2}$$

$$\implies \frac {\bar u}{2} - \left | u - \frac {\bar u}{2}\right| \geq 0$$

**ADDENDUM**
In a comment it was proposed that we could instead use the squared expression to achieve differentiability everywhere,

$$\frac {\bar{u}^2}{4} - \left ( u - \frac {\bar u}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$

Let's see: we then are allowed to decompose the square and write

$$\frac {\bar{u}^2}{4} - u^2 + u\bar u - \frac {\bar{u}^2}{4} \geq 0$$

$$\implies -u^2 + \bar u u \geq 0 \implies u(\bar u -u) \geq 0$$

which is nothing more than *the multiplication* of the two separate constraints.

**ADDENDUM II**
If we have $u \in [a,b]$ for $a<b$ arbitrary reals, then the general expression is

$$-u^2+(a+b)u-ab\geq 0$$

Comment: Nice! But $$\frac {\bar{u}^2}{4} - \left ( u - \frac {\bar u}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$ is even better because it is differentiable everywhere, even in $u = \frac {\bar u}{2}$.

Comment: @denesp By all means - and it gets even better.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is it conincidence that it's just the multiplication of the two seperate constraints, or some general rule?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Good decomposition but actually you have just shown that all our rules so far are incorrect :) Your new condition also holds if $u < 0$ AND $\bar u < u$ :( If $\bar u < 0$ is impossible then we are fine though.

Comment: @denesp These inequalities cannot hold at the same time.

Comment: @denesp Writing $[0,\bar u]$ always means that $\bar u \geq 0$.

Comment: You are probably right, it seems to be implied by the problem.